# How to save app for startActivityForResult()?

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog

I have an app, which requests an image with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then user chooses an app from dialog with options "ALWAYS" and "JUST ONCE". The problem is that "ALWAYS" doesn't work. When `startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);` is called the second time, the dialog raises again. How should I handle this?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            try {
                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        data.getData());
                originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code in startActivityForResult.

Comment: private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;

Comment: Not your requestCode - your source code. ;)

Comment: Where do you get "ALWAYS" or "ONLY_NOW" and save them in SharedPreferences or in a file?